# Difference between "Bpmn2 Diagram Editor" and "BPMN2 Process Editor"

Tags: java, eclipse, jbpm, bpmn

The jbpm-6.1.0.Final-installer-full.zip from http://www.jbpm.org/ archive contains an eclipse Kepler distribution with plugins to edit bpmn diagrams.

From the eclipse Kepler i've imported a maven project with some .bpmn files (initially created with jbpm5 eclipse Helios process editor), that i'd like to modify.

From the Package Explorer, right-click on a .bpmn file then select "Open With" there are:

- **Bpmn2 Diagram Editor**: more features but looks more complex
- **BPMN2 Process Editor**: less feature and similar the jbpm5 eclipse Helios editor

The 6.1 userguide http://docs.jboss.com/jbpm/v6.1/userguide/ does not contain any information about the process editor.

What is the difference between them ? Which one should i use ? Is there any benefits of using this version comparing to the process editor in jbpm5 eclipse ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BPMN2 Process Editor is the old editor that was used in jBPM5.  It's still included for backwards compatibility reason, but we would strongly encourage you to use the BPMN2 Diagram Editor, as this is much more complete.

This is also probably the reason why it looks more complex, because it supports a lot more types of nodes and properties.  Note that you however could configure which elements / attributes you want to see for your model in the Preferences, if you want to simplify.